# navbar tailwind does not disappear at xl

Tags: menu, navbar, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I have this navbar that I would like to close already in lg or xl size and not in md size. I would like to understand how with alpine js:

```
<div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>
    
    <div x-data="{ sidebarOpen: false }" class="flex h-screen bg-gray-200">
        <div :class="sidebarOpen ? 'block' : 'hidden'" @click="sidebarOpen = false" class="fixed z-20 inset-0 bg-black opacity-50 transition-opacity lg:hidden"></div>
    
        <div :class="sidebarOpen ? 'translate-x-0 ease-out' : '-translate-x-full ease-in'" class="fixed z-30 inset-y-0 left-0 w-64 transition duration-300 transform bg-gray-900 overflow-y-auto lg:translate-x-0 lg:static lg:inset-0">
```

I did not understand how to close this sidebar already in xl size with alpine js and tailwind

[image]

Below is the link for the entire code:

https://tailwindcomponents.com/component/dashboard-template

i didn't quite understand how to use sidebar Open

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you are trying to make the sidebar open and close. You can create the `div` for the sidebar and the `div` for the button that will be used to toggle.

You can use `x-show="sidebarOpen = true"` on the div that you want to show up when the sidebar is enabled.

Doing `@click="sidebarOpen !sidebarOpen"` will toggle the inverse state. So you can click the same button to show the sidebar, and close it.

```
<div x-data="{ sidebarOpen: false }" class="flex h-screen bg-gray-200">
        {{-- This is sidebar button --}}
        <div @click="sidebarOpen !sidebarOpen" class=" fixed z-20 inset-0 bg-black opacity-50 transition-opacity"></div>
    
        {{-- This Is Sidebar Content --}}
        <div x-show="sidebarOpen = true" class="fixed z-30 inset-y-0 left-0 w-64 transition duration-300 transform bg-gray-900 overflow-y-auto lg:translate-x-0 lg:static lg:inset-0">

        </div>
</div>
```